# how to use this working regular expression (re) on a pandas df to remove redundant non-numeric character , asterisk (*)?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

By using the code below, I am able to use **re** to change a string like this: `*12.2` to a float number like this: `12.2`:

```
import re
numeric_const_pattern = '[-+]? (?: (?: \d* \. \d+ ) | (?: \d+ \.? ) )(?: [Ee] [+-]? \d+ ) ?'
rx = re.compile(numeric_const_pattern, re.VERBOSE)
print('converted string to float number is', float(rx.findall("*12.2")[0]))

converted string to float number is 12.2
```

But I have a pandas df, which is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[10, '*41', '-0.01', '2'],['*10.5', 54, 34.2, '*-0.076'], 
                        [65, -32.01, '*344.32', 0.01], ['*32', '*0', 5, 43]])


       0         1         2          3
0      10       *41      -0.01        2
1     *10.5      54       34.2      *-0.076
2      65       -32.01   *344.32      0.01
3     *32       *0        5           43
```

How can I apply the function above to this df in order to remove all of asterisk characters and also make a complete float dtype pandas df like below?

```
       0       1       2          3
0      10      41     -0.01       2
1      10.5    54      34.2      -0.076
2      65     -32.01   344.32     0.01
3      32      0       5          43
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Simple

```
df.replace('[^\d\.eE+-]', '', regex=True).astype(float)

      0      1       2       3
0  10.0  41.00   -0.01   2.000
1  10.5  54.00   34.20  -0.076
2  65.0 -32.01  344.32   0.010
3  32.0   0.00    5.00  43.000
```

---

#### A little more robust

```
df.replace('[^\d\.eE+-]', '', regex=True).apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')

      0      1       2       3
0  10.0  41.00   -0.01   2.000
1  10.5  54.00   34.20  -0.076
2  65.0 -32.01  344.32   0.010
3  32.0   0.00    5.00  43.000
```

Comment: Thank you very much. So, this df.replace method accepts regex just like **re** library? very interesting.

Comment: Yes, it uses the `re` library in fact.  But you have to set the flag `regex=True`

Answer (score 2):

A little verbose, but here's a viable non-regex based solution using `melt` and `str.rpartition`.

```
v = df.melt()['value'].astype(str).str.rpartition('*')[2]
df = pd.DataFrame(v.values.astype(float).reshape(df.shape))

df
       0       1       2     3
0  10.00  10.500   65.00  32.0
1  41.00  54.000  -32.01   0.0
2  -0.01  34.200  344.32   5.0
3   2.00  -0.076    0.01  43.0
```

Comment: @hyTuev Do you have more than 1 asterisk somewhere?